# Iterating over different collections in an Enum

Tags: rust, iterator

I have an enum with two variants. One of these variants contains a Vec and the other contains a BTreeMap. I'd like to be able to iterate over these two contains. Actually, I like to "massage" the Vec so it behaves like the BTreeMap where the value is fixed at 1. The setup is as follows:

```
pub struct Sketch {
    pub name: String,
    pub hashes: Vec<u64>,
}

pub struct WeightedSketch {
    pub name: String,
    pub hashes: BTreeMap<u64, u32>,
}

pub enum SketchType {
    Unweighted(Sketch),
    Weighted(WeightedSketch),
}

impl SketchType {
    pub fn hashes(&self) -> Iter<u64, u32> {
        match self {
            SketchType::Weighted(sketch) => sketch.hashes.iter(),
            SketchType::Unweighted(sketch) => sketch.hashes.iter().map(|hash| (*hash, 1 as u32)).collect::<BTreeMap<u64, u32>>().iter(), 
        }
    }
}
```

This does not compile, but more critically does not seem like the right general approach. As a simple example, I'd like to be able to do things like the following regardless of the variant of the SketchType:

```
fn do_work(sketch: &SketchType) -> u64 {
    sketch.values().map(|v| *v as u64).sum()
}
```

Is an Enum the correct approach here? Do I need to somehow implement the Iterator trait for SketchType?

Thanks,
Donovan

Comment: This question is missing an MRE. What is `ItemHash`?

Comment: Also... _"This compiles"_ -- it shouldn't. The `Unweighted` arm tries to return a value referencing the temporary `BTreeMap`. So either the statement that it compiles is wrong, or you are asking about different code than what you have shown here. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Thanks @cdhowie. I changed the ItemHash to a u64, and updated the question to indicate the code does not compile as written. I think it captures my aim, but my guess is that my general approach is flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use itertools::{Itertools, Either}; // 0.11.0

pub struct Sketch {
    pub name: String,
    pub hashes: Vec<u64>,
}

pub struct WeightedSketch {
    pub name: String,
    pub hashes: BTreeMap<u32, u64>,
}

pub enum SketchType {
    Unweighted(Sketch),
    Weighted(WeightedSketch),
}


impl SketchType {
    /// An iterator through the hash values.
    fn values(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=u64> + '_ {
        // To reconcile the fact that each branch returns a different type of
        // iterator, we make use of `itertools::Either`, which is designed
        // exactly for that.
        match *self {
            SketchType::Unweighted(ref sketch) => 
                Either::Left(sketch.hashes.iter().cloned()),
            SketchType::Weighted(ref sketch) =>
                Either::Right(sketch.hashes.values().cloned())
        }
    }

    /// Look, `do_work` works!
    fn do_work(&self) -> u64 {
        self.values().sum()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yoric. Yes, this is what I had in mind. Is this performant or is having to clone the iterators a substantial overhead? Would there be any benefit to implementing Iterator on Sketch and WeightedSketch to indicate that iteration should be over the collection in the struct?

Comment: Would it be more performant to use a Box or is this largely the same since you need to allocate the Box: `pub fn hash_iter(&self) -> Box<dyn ExactSizeIterator<Item=&u64> + '_> { ... }`.

Comment: @DHP `Either` (or the equivalent manual implementation) has the advantage that there is no heap allocation to store the iterator, and the disadvantage that there is a branch on each `Iterator::next` invocation (though the CPU's branch prediction will likely handle that). Boxing into a `dyn Iterator` has the advantage of not branching, but requiring a heap allocation and making an indirect function call on each `Iterator::next` call. I suspect that `Either` is going to be the better option by far.

Comment: @DHP *"... is having to clone the iterators a substantial overhead?"* - this isn't actually cloning the iterator, its cloning the elements (`clone` vs [`cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned)). That is used since `.iter()` yields references (`&u64`) and it makes it yield values (`u64`) instead, which for a primitive type like `u64` would not harbor any overhead.

Comment: You can use `copied()` instead.